# размер экрана в симуляторе xcode iphone или ipad

Tags: xcode, swift

Добрый день или вечер всем!

Изучаю тут swift в xcode

Возникла проблема как найти разрешение экрана телефона или планшета автоматически. У меня например есть игра и в ней нужно, чтобы задний фон растягивался под указанное разрешение автоматически

я попробовал вот так:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height

//let screenWidth = screenSize.width * 0.75

let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
myLabel.text = "\(screenSize.height, screenSize.width)"
myLabel.fontSize = 25
myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

self.addChild(myLabel)

let Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "desert_BG")
let BackgroundSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: Texture)
BackgroundSprite.size = CGSizeMake(1136, 650) 
BackgroundSprite.position = CGPointMake(0, 0) 
BackgroundSprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
BackgroundSprite.name = "BackgroundSprite"
self.addChild(BackgroundSprite)
```

Симулятор iphone 5 у него разрешение экрана iphone 5,5s - 1136 x 640, 326 ppi, а почему он показывает 320.0, 568,0

Answer (score 1):

Вы правильно узнаете размер экрана

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
```

Но, размер экрана измеряется в поинтах, таким образом и у iPhone4 и у iPhone5 будет 320x568.

При этом можно узнать scale factor (множитель при переводе поинтов в пиксели) используя

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

и исходя их этого посчитать. Если, например, у вас iPhone5, с ретина дисплеем, scale=2.0, то етсь разрешение экрана в пикселях 640x1336.

При этом хочу добавить, что обычно при разработке вам эта информация не нужна. все координаты все равно даются в поинтах, а если вам надо выбрать какой детализации изображение использовать, просто дайте системе все изображения и она выберет подходящее по ситуации. (см. @2x naming)

Comment: ну мне банально нужно, чтобы картинка которую я добавил растягивалась на полный экран (это как бы мой задний фон), ему же дается рамеры в пикселях(или я не правильно понимаю). т.е. мне нужно все это умножить на scale factor ?

Comment: нет, размеры всегда в поинтах. bounds это все, что вам надо знать, чтоб растянуть картинку на весь экран.

Comment: другими словами, если ваше изображение хранится, например, в imageView, вот такой код `imageView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` отработает правильно на всех девайсах и ничего больше делать вам не надо.

Comment: я извинясь, но у меня почему то не получается выдает вот такую картину http://s019.radikal.ru/i624/1602/2c/fb0b88f3d6ed.png

Comment: залейте весь код куда нить, посмотрю что у вас там не так

Comment: это простейший проект я только начал изучать я залил папку из проекта, где лежит gameViewController . я просто не понимаю может проект насет в себе дополнительную инф. которую нельзя показывать публично. проект тут ну там все пару строк так, как  я вообще зеленый в этом деле https://github.com/maxandmax/gameSwiftTests

Comment: В репозитории нет .proj файла

Comment: вот может это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265495/scene-size-in-xcode-6-spritekit-swift

Comment: ок. посмотрю спасибо

Comment: Вы бекграунд ставите в координаты 0:0 экрана и сам бекграунд у вас выступает, (почти) также как и спрайт. Есть такая штука как anchorPoint. По умолчанию (если мне не изменяет память) у него координаты: ширина / 2 и высота / 2 (т.е. по центру спрайта). Через то у вас и съезжает бекграунд, т.к. его нулевая координата стоит в центре. почитайте об anchorPoint - найдете решение.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Interface Builder, то вы можете все сделать в нем без единой сточки кода. Вернее такие задачи и нужно делать в нем.

Добавляете UImageView на сцену. Заполняете ей все пространство.
Добавляете 4 констрейнта. Выбираете нужный вам scale. Если используете разные ориентации, выбираете нужный Size Class и далаете layout для него.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]